# How to store multi-valued attributes in PostGis using Postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, fields-attributes

I have a with meterid,meterreading,reader and date read.I wish to store this data using Postgis database.

[image: table]

I used this code via postgresql to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE MeterRdg(
    meterid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    reading integer,
    reader VARCHAR(15),
    DateRead date)
```

I then tried to insert data into the table using the following command

```
INSERT INTO MeterRdg(meterid, reading,reader,DateRead)
VALUES
('M1',871.31,'Kamau','26/02/2015'),
('M2',624.53,'Kamau','26/02/2015'),
('M3',531.47,'Kamau','27/02/2015'),
('M1',926.44,'Ochieng','25/03/2015'),
('M2',761.31,'Ochieng','26/03/2015'),
('M3',683.51,'Ochieng','26/03/2015')
```

I get the following error:

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "meterrdg_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (meterid)=(M1) already exists.

[image: this error]

How can I redesign the CREATE table command such that M1,M2,M3 can hold multi-values?

Comment: This is unrelated to GIS, but you should review the meaning of "primary key".

Comment: its related to GIS, the database am creating is a spatial one, hosted on PostGIS(a spatial database) and visualization and analysis on QGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `meterid` as a `PRIMARY KEY` so they should be unique.

You may use Composite Key

```
CREATE TABLE MeterRdg(
    meterid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    reading integer,
    reader VARCHAR(15),
    DateRead date,
    PRIMARY KEY(meterid, DateRead)
)
```

or add a column with counter and use it as a key for whole record

```
CREATE TABLE MeterRdg(
    record_key    serial primary key,
    meterid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    reading integer,
    reader VARCHAR(15),
    DateRead date
)
```

Comment: in the first option, I presume that date you meant Dateread in defining the primary key........ PRIMARY KEY(meterid, date) such that it should be  PRIMARY KEY(meterid, DateRead)

Comment: Yes, I've messed them. You may choose any set of columns to be Composite Key.